# FFT plot not aligning with lower natural frequencies

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency, spring, vibrations, structural-beam

I have a cantilever beam with gapped springs on top and bottom and an impulse is given at the free end initially.

I modelled it using finite element method with 30 elements.

[image]

The beam then oscillates vertically and when the beam displacement at a node (between 2 elements) is equal to or larger than the gap, then it is as if another linear spring is added to the beam at that point.

[image]

like here, a spring is added to the middle because the vertical displacement of middle is $>=$ GAP. And the spring will only be removed when the vertical displacement $<$ GAP

I found the response(of the end point) and when I took FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) of response, this is what I get

[image]

This is how the displacement of the end point of beam varies with time. red lines are the gap.

[image]

Here red vertical lines are meant to be natural frequencies.

The higher frequencies match with FFT response but lower frequencies does not.

**Could someone provide some insights on why this is happening?**

I am solving it using FEM (Finite Element Method, 30 elements) in Python with [solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html)

Comment: When you say you "found the response", how exactly did you do that? Did you do a simulation of some kind? What kind?  Or did you measure the physical system?

Comment: time response. i.e. vertical displacement at each node from time 0 to 8 seconds.

Comment: How did you get the second graph? How did you get the natural frequencies? Amplitude response to harmonic excitation should have maxima somewhat lower than resonant frequencies, due to dissipation (this is easiest to see for a damped linear harmonic oscillator).

Comment: got second graph by taking fast fourier transform of the displacement of end point of the beam(first figure). got natural frequencies from eigenvalues. It is an impulse not harmonic excitation.